# Android Multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I am doing experiment and trying to combine these 2 projects into single project:
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/65.html
http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/01/copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sd.html
I would like to make the "Using intent demo" has extra functionality of copy asset to SD card.
What I did was copied the java files from "AssetsToSdCard" to "IntentActionDemo". Then I added the following line to IntentActionDemo manifest:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
```

However, the files won't copy to SD card. If I replace the "IntentActionDemo" to "MainActivity", then the files will be copied to SD card.

```
    <activity android:name=".IntentActionDemo"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It seems like in order to get the copy asset to SD card work, I have to put it as the first activity and put intent.action.MAIN as well as intent.category.LAUNCHER.

What I should do if I want IntentActionDemo as the first activity, IntentA as the second and MainActivity (AssetsToSdCard) as the third activity? I would like the files copied to SD card automatically on first startup, not onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this code in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".IntentActionDemo"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
<activity android:name=".IntentA"></activity>
```

and in IntentA.java change

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, IntentActionDemo.class);
```

to

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

Check out Android API Guides about [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and [Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) for more informations. Probably you will also find useful [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) description.

Comment: Thanks, the files were copied to SD card onclick. However, this is not what I want. I would like to make files copied automatically on first startup. How I should do?

Comment: Problem solved. I realised that I need to edit the java file.